# create a sub list of elements based on user input

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I wrote the code below, where from an initialized list of countries the method will return all the countries who have a longitude of >= 5, the code works but now I want the method to return the name of countries that are close to String D within a 5 degrees range of longitude.

I tried implementing the scanner as shown below but I still get countries that have longitude higher than 5. how can I make the method return the name of countries based on the user input.

```
ArrayList<String> CountriesDistance= new ArrayList<>(); 
Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter The Name of a Country: ");  
String D= scanner.nextLine(); 
for(Country country : Countries)
    if (!CountriesDistance.contains(country.CountryName.equals(D)) && country.getLongitude() >= 5)
        CountriesDistance.add(country.CountryName); 
    System.out.println(CountriesDistance);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your if statement.

You are writing following ...

```
if (!CountriesDistance.contains(country.CountryName.equals(D)) && country.getLongitude() >= 5)
```

The "country.CountryName.equals(D)" part returns true or false. So you are checking if CountriesDistance not contains true/false AND if the longitude of the country is greater or equal to 5.

I guess you ment:

```
if(!CountriesDistance.contains(inputCountryAsString) && (country.getLongitude() <= baseCountry.getLongitude() + 5 && country.getLongitude() >= baseCountry.getLongitude() - 5))
```

I initialized baseCountry like this:

```
Country baseCountry = getCountryByName(countries, inputCountry);
public static Country getCountryByName(Countries countries, String name) {
    Country country = null;
    for (Country c : Countries) {
        if (c.getName().equals(name))
            country = c;
    }
    return country;
}
```

In this case I got the name of the Country by calling getName() which I implemented like this:

```
class Country {

    String countryName;

    public String getName() {
        return countryName;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that, the only thing left is how can I make the method return a list of countries that have higher Longitude than String D the input of the user

Comment: So, the Countries are printed correctly now?

Comment: actually it only returns String D to me now, it doesn't return any other countries

Comment: Okay perhaps I understand your question now.
Remove the "country.CountryName.equals(D) && " part in the if statement. (I corrected it in the answer.)

Comment: Done I did that

Comment: But it does not work like it should, does it?
Can you publish more code?

Comment: other than the code for reading the text file that is all the code I wrote so far. what if I implement compare to and create a sorting algorithm. Do you think that will do

Comment: Actually you need the if statement to check if (1) the current country is NOT in the list and (2) the current country longitude is within a range of 5 degrees of the country with the name D.
So you have to get the country object which has the name D. It is hard to write valid code if I don't know if you can get a country by name for example.

Comment: yes, you can get the country by its name, if I write Canada and it is in the list the method should be able to find it and access it Longitude.

Comment: I will definitely keep the if statement, but after I confirm that the country String D is in the list can I compare it with the remaining of the list using compare to

Comment: Please take a look at the answer ... I hope it is clear.